# Where to find the new Microsoft's mso icons

Tags: user-interface, icons, office365, add-in

I just found out that with one of the last Office update, Microsoft's icons have been reworked, they have got new skins and all for Office 32bits.

This means some of the Mso icons are no longer available or have their identifier changed, and are displayed like so in add-ins:
[image: Broken Mso]

I'm trying to adapt an Excel add-in in order to replace the broken Msos to keep a decent visual between the old and new versions.

It means I have to handle this kind of thing for each single given Mso identifier:
Old version -> [image: Old version]
New version -> [image: New version]

There were documents for Office in order to find Msos and their respective Id [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21103), but I can't find any equivalent for the new ones.
I've seen [the list of identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745), but nothing that actually let me see the icon and its Mso identifier.
Is there anything that could help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Office 2010 icon names and images from the word file downloadable here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21103

These mso_  labels work in VS ribbons even if the user has the new version of office. Although the icons themselves have changed, in my experience they look similar enough to work in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to use the new Office SVG images within a custom ribbon. The old images were a stored collection of MSO images and now they seem to be changing to a new scale-able SVG image set.

The Newer MSO images however are available to those using Newer versions of Office and the MSO image names are identical to the previous MSO image Set from the older versions of Office.

Comment: Hi James ! Thank you for answering me. This is a nice answer, however you can actually use the new icons in an XML Ribbon for Excels add-in. This topic is a bit old now, at the time I ended up downloading a Visual Studio add-in that helped me browse and auto-complete the icons within the XML code. Unfortunately I can't recall nor find the name of the add-in.